# How to fix Wget parameter name "C" is ambigous?

Tags: wget

I'm trying to find a solution for failed download on chrome, resume can't fix it so I tried to do research if there's any possibility to resume my download then I find this site [How to Resume an Interrupted Download in Google Chrome](https://www.howtogeek.com/437204/how-to-resume-an-interrupted-download-in-google-chrome/#:%7E:text=To%20open%20the%20download%20manager,item%20and%20click%20%E2%80%9CResume%E2%80%9D.)

The problem is the parameter name C is ambiguous, I don't know if it should be run in cmd, not Windows Power Shell because it only works for me in Power Shell when I tried it in cmd it says Wget is not recognized as an internal or external command.

[image: Windows Power Shell Result]

Answer (score 1):

Try using lowercase 'c' for your argument.

```
$ wget --help | grep continue
  -c,  --continue                  resume getting a partially-downloaded file
```

Comment: Can you try an ordinary msdos prompt instead of powershell?